Org mode capture template that lets one select repeater interval
The following in a capture template lets one select the scheduled date and appends a repeater interval
SCHEDULED: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t) nil nil nil nil \" ++1m\")

Is there a way to let the user pick up the repeater interval? So, may be, the capture template will ask for some text and insert it in place of '++1m'?

Avoid such complications: just enter the plain entry using  the template (no dates! no repeaters! no scheduled/deadline keywords!) and schedule it afterwards (immediately or during the nightly or weekly review).
